# phplist test emails failing inconsistently

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phplist

I recently performed a parallel update from phplist 2.10.12 to 3.0.12. We kept the old version operational while the client became accustomed to the new one in demo mode. Today we switched to 3.0.12 and turned off demo mode, and we're having difficulty with the test emails.

phplist is configured to send two test emails, one in text and one in html. When sending a test to me, both emails are sent (and are put in spam), and phplist announces that they were sent successfully. When sending a test email to the client, however, only the text message is sent successfully. When changing the setting to only send one email, phplist announces that sending failed, and indeed no email shows up.

The client is indeed capable of receiving html emails at that address, and the error log says `Error sending email to [email address] Could not instantiate mail function.` However, to reiterate, it *did* send correctly to me - twice. But it fails every time sending to the client.

I am unfamiliar with configuring phplist, and any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: from config.php:

```
# To use a SMTP server please give your server hostname here, leave it blank to use the standard
# PHP mail() command.
define("PHPMAILERHOST",'');
```

Comment: I suggest you start looking into your servers error log file... I mean do I get this right, you are _selling_ that service, and you run into such problems?

Comment: and the mail servers log file

Comment: error_log is not available on this server for some reason. I can contact the webhost about it, but if it's a programmatic thing that can be corrected, that's easier. The previous phplist didn't have this problem, it's new with 3.0.12 on this install.

Comment: I have contacted the webhost to request the error logs for the server and emails